# Addition in java script gives wrong data or Nan

Tags: javascript, excel

I am calculating the data using addition. When iam calculating, I am getting the wrong output

hear AS6 i need to get the output 7.81 but i am either getting wrong value or Nan.
Please help me where i went wrong.

Comment: Try to use numerical values for variables that contain numbers, rather than using strings... Also, if you have integers, will you get integer division (thus rounding)? What happens if you print out each of the individual variables `ab` through `ar`? That should help you pinpoint your problem.

Comment: Hi,it is giving empty data ar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all parseInt('') is NaN, thats why you are getting NaN.

Also, I think you should be using

```
AS6 = parseFloat(ab) + parseFloat(ac) + .........
```

for correct result because when you do parseInt it will return only Integer value not the fraction part. So obviously after adding all together you will be getting a Integer only not a float. and when you use parseFloat on Integer it will just return that integer only.

So to avoid NaN and parseInt you can finally do like

```
AS6 = Number(ab) + Number(ac) + .........
```

to get correct results. As Number('') is 0 So you don't need to worry about NaN anymore.

Note: Number('10.11') is 10.11

Answer (score 0):

`parseInt('')` is `NaN` and `NaN + n` (where n is any integer) is also NaN.

Comment: As @Floris mentioned, don't start by using strings. Just use numbers and `null`;